# ALERT! encrypted source device uuid=longstring Does not exist, can't unlock nvme0n1p3_crypt

Tags: 20.04, backup, restore, initramfs, timeshift

1. I just installed a fresh Ubuntu 20.04 machine with all my needed programs.
2. I used TimeShift to create a full system backup (my drive is encrypted).
3. I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on yet a machine and loaded the backup created of the first machine.
4. Everything looked okay - but then this message showed up (because it is restored on another machine):

> ```
> ALERT! encrypted source device uuid=longstring Does not exist, can't unlock nvme0n1p3_crypt.
> ```

Is it possible to fix this issue? In your answer please elaborate in detail I'm not an Ubuntu/Linux expert.

Comment: Hi. were you able to solve this issue? I face the same issue and not able to proceed

Comment: Nope - and I don't think it can be solved considering the time consumption vs. re-installing a fresh machine...thats at least what I ended up doing after hours of google-search...

Comment: Actually, in my case, it was some BIOS settings that got changed to some invalid value. Changing it back worked. Saved me lot of time for setting everything up.